# I can't upload image to backend with fetch in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring

I will get to the point right away.

I have this simple form in REACT. It has 2 input fields and 1 image upload filed. I need to send data to backend API which is made with Spring.

I am trying this right now

```js
const formID = document.getElementById('formGroup');
const formData = new FormData(formID);

fetch('api/5/add-image', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then(res => {
   this.setState({ isSubmitting: false });
   console.log(res.text());
})
```

But I constantly get the same error message in the console

`Required request part 'file' is not present`

Any ideas what could cause the problem? Authentication token works and headers are okay I think.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not stringify the form values and don't specify the Content-Type header when using FormData and fetch

This should do it

```js
const formID = document.getElementById('formGroup');
const formData = new FormData(formID);
fetch('api/5/add-image', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    Accept: 'application/json',
  }
}).then(res => {
   this.setState({ isSubmitting: false });
   console.log(res.text());
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but ```Current request is not a multipart form request``` is a message I get now after I removed ```Content-Type```

**EDIT** Sorry. My mistake. I still get the same error about file not being present

Comment: Have you double-checked that the `name` attribute of the file input is the same as your server expects it to be?

Comment: Thank you so much. You have no idea how long I've tried to do this. That was the problem. Thank you.